# Capture EventEmitter in Angular before it is unsubscribed

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am using Angular10 and I have the following template (PSEUDO CODE)

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" *ngIf="isOpen">
    <div class="dropdown-item" (beforeClick)="isOpen = false" (confirmClick)="delete()">Delete</div>

</div>
```

The confirm click is a custom directive:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[confirmClick]'
})
export class ConfirmClickDirective {
    @Output()
    public beforeClick = new EventEmitter();

    @Output('confirmClick')
    public clickConfirmed = new EventEmitter();

    @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
    public onClick(event: Event) {
        this.beforeClick.emit();

        this.dialogs.confirm(...).pipe(take(1))
            .subscribe(confirmed => {
                if (confirmed) {
                    this.clickConfirmed.emit();
                }
            });
    }
}
```

What happens is the following:

1. User opens the dropdown menu.
2. User clicks the delete button.
3. Dropdown menu is closed and all events are unbinded.
4. Confirm dialog is shown.
5. clickConfirmed is trigger but has no more subscribers

Is there a good way to capture the eventemitter before calling beforeClick?`

I have one workaround, but it is super ugly:

```
@HostListener('click', ['$event'])
public onClick(event: Event) {
    const observers = [...this.clickConfirmed.observers];

    this.beforeClick.emit();

    this.dialogs.confirm(this.confirmTitle, this.confirmText).pipe(take(1))
        .subscribe(confirmed => {
            if (confirmed) {
                for (const observer of observers) {
                    const subscriber = observer as Subscriber<any>;

                    if (subscriber['destination'] && subscriber['destination'].next) {
                        subscriber['destination'].next(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
}
```

One solution would be obviously not to use *ngIf, but I have a few complex dropdown menu

Comment: Try ` <div class="dropdown-item" (click)="isOpen = false; delete()">Delete</div>` basically on click event you can first close the isOpened dropdown and then call delete() method.

Comment: Yes, I know, but this is not what I want. It would show the dropdown and the modal at the same time.

Comment: I would send the delete command as an action in a store or via a `Subject` in a shared service.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you can do is to use an IIFE to *copy* the initial subject:

```js
@HostListener('click', ['$event'])
public onClick(event: Event) {
  this.beforeClick.emit();

  const afterConfirmed = (confirmed => (saved = confirmed, () => saved.emit()))(this.clickConfirmed);

  this.dialogs.confirm(...).pipe(take(1))
    .subscribe(confirmed => {
        if (confirmed) {
            // this.clickConfirmed.emit();
            afterConfirmed();
        }
    });
}
```

Here's another snippet that explains my reasoning:

```js
o = { test: 'andrei' }

foo = (o => (crt = o.test, () => crt))(o);

o.test = 'abcdefgh'

foo() // "andrei"
```

Comment: the problem is that the observers of the subject are closed. Therefore I had to go to the destination of the observer directly.